# How to get the Filename in code behind on selecting a file, before uploading it to the server using aspx and CS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I want to retrieve the file name and perform some validation on that filename. so before uploading i have to get the filename of the file selected for uploading.

Actually what i wanted is to get the filename and retrieve some fields from database based on which file is chosen , and send the data retrieved from database on the client side in some textfield. So for that before on click of upload i need to call a method in code behind which will validate all these things. I tried using AjaxControlToolkit, its not working.

Comment: use `Path.GetFileName` or `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`

Answer (score 0):

Use [GetFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. Below example from MSDN link.

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the filename on the client prior to sending it to the server you will not be able to do so with C#, you could quite easiy write a validation function in Javascript however.

You could perform server side validation of the file, but that would mean **after** uploading it. You could then make sure the file fulfills all your validation criterias and if it for some reason fails validation you could return the error message to the user. But that would mean a full postback of the page.

Answer (score 0):

See below code example to get the file name :

```
var filePath = "C:\\SpiderCode\\MyFile.txt";
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Client Side Code

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload" Width="100px" />
```

In code behind, check if user select any file, then it will simply gives you the file name in the `fileName` variable.

```
if (FileUpload.HasFile)
{
    string fileName = FileUpload.FileName;
}
```