# How to get the Filename in code behind on selecting a file, before uploading it to the server using aspx and CS? & using spl tech if required any

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I want to retrieve the file name and perform some validation on that filename. so before uploading i have to get the filename of the file selected for uploading.

Actually what i wanted is to get the filename and retrieve some fields from database based on which file is chosen , and send the data retrieved from database on the client side in some textfield. So for that before on click of upload i need to call a method in code behind which will validate all these things. I tried using AjaxControlToolkit, its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Filename in code behind on selecting a file, before uploading it to the server using aspx and CS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218023/how-to-get-the-filename-in-code-behind-on-selecting-a-file-before-uploading-it)

Answer (score 0):

If it is in javascript/jquery you can use:

```
var fileName = $(element).val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, "");
```

If in C# you can use:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName Or System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
```